# Cannot kill the process javaw.exe from Minecraft

Tags: java, process, kill, minecraft

I start up Minecraft, close it using Quit game or press the close button and the window closes but not the javaw.exe process and when I try to kill it in the Task manager nothing happens. When I try to kill it in Process Explorer nothing happens either, not even when killing the tree, suspending it first etc.

It's eating up all of my PC's memory and the process will only close when a reboot happens and won't close when logging out and in. I googled around and some people are having it too but they don't seem to be finding any solution.

Comment: Have you scanned for malware recently?

Comment: Which version of Java, which OS (edition and bit-level)?

Comment: Isn't any other application still running on **JDK** (_javaw.exe_ process)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a reported bug for Minecraft (reported officially today).

See bug [MC-1408 "Javaw.exe keeps running after closing minecraft"](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-1408).

More info in [this MC thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1405977-minecrafts-java-process-will-not-die-on-closure-or-at-all-for-that-matter/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been struggling with this since 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't close the launcher or the Minecraft game you're playing is because the bug that is caused by the new update.

You would have to log off then log back in again or you can fully shut it down and re-open it but it would just normally come up with start window or configure some stuff.

Another problem you may have due to the new update is playing on multiplayer servers, sometimes you would just come out of the server and come up with some JavaScript net stuff or it would close the server and log you out.